# How to re-create Facebook image modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I want to create something almost exactly like the Facebook image modal wherein the image is fixed while a user scrolls through the comments. I am messing with different ways to apply `overflow: hidden` to one div and `overflow: scroll` to the other. I even looked into applying it to their parent. Here is the code I've tried:

```
<div class="row container border border-primary">
  <div class="image col border">
    Image
  </div>
  <div class="text-section col border">
    Comments
  </div>
</div>

div.image {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.text-section {
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

div.container {
  height: 300px;
}
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7ezLDhmzIvpGGFtd?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Could you possibly show an example of what exactly you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I supposed a code like this. The blue (image) remains fixed on the left, while you can scroll the green section (comments) on the right

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <style>
      #container { background: red; width: 400px; height: 150px; display: flex; }
      #image     { background: url("https://i1.adis.ws/i/canon/canon-pro-best-landscape-lenses-1-1140?w=200&aspect=4:3&qlt=70&sm=aspect&fmt=jpg&fmt.options=interlaced&fmt=jpg&fmt.options=interlaced&bg=rgb(255,255,255)"); width: 200px; height: 150px; }
      #comments  { background: #eee; width: 200px; overflow: scroll; padding: 0 10px 20px 10px; font-family: Verdana; color: black; }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="image"></div>
      <div id="comments">
         <h3 style="color: red;">Comments</h3>
         <p>Nice!</p>
         <p>Good!</p>
         <p>Wonderful</p>
         <p>Bah...</p>
         <p>Strange</p>
         <p>Nice again</p>
         <p>Amazing</p>
         <p>Beautiful</p>
         <p>Great</p>
         <p>I don’t like it</p>
         <p>Yes, nice</p>
         <p>Super</p>
         <p>Normal</p>
         <p>Ok...</p>
         <p>Nice</p>
         <p>Bah</p>
         <p>Great</p>
         <p>Nice</p>
         <p>I like it</p>
         <p>Normal</p>
      </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works suprisingly! I might have to look at the other complications in my code as to why it's not working on mine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have facebook so cant look at the behaviour, but you could put `position: sticky;` on the image container, that will keep it in place. It also depends on your browser support, like ie11 [does not support it](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky), but there are more ways to do this. Let me know if you need a more cross browser solution.

```css
.container {
  max-height: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div.image {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

div.text-section {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="row container border border-primary">
  <div class="image col border">
    Image
  </div>
  <div class="text-section col border">
    Comments
  </div>
</div>
```